# If-for-else nested set comprehension in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, set-comprehension

I'm trying to convert the following nested conditions to set comprehension, but couldn't get it working properly.

```py
processed = set()
if isinstance(statements, list):
    for action in statements:
        processed.add(action)
else:
    processed.add(statements)
```

I tried the following but looks I'm making a mistake

```py
processed = {action for action in statements if isinstance(statements, list) else statements}
```

Edit: Where `statements` can be a list or string.

Comment: what is ```statements```? Please provide that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `if` statement outside the set comprehension, as in the `else` case, `statements` is not an iterable

```py
processed = {action for action in statements} if isinstance(statements, list) else {statements}
```

Comment: that's better than the `{a for a in (statements if isinstance(statements, list) else [statements])}` I had in mind

Comment: instead of `{action for action in statements}` you could just do `set(statements)` to simplify it a bit.

Comment: @big_bad_bison true, the reason I did it like this was the question asked specifically for a set comprehension

Comment: Thanks all, looks like this is the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
proceed={x for x in statements} if isinstance(statements, list) else statements
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have to use set-comprehension AT ANY PRICE then your code might be simplified by using `.update` method of `set`, which accept iterable and has same effect as using `.add` for each element of iterable. Simplified code:

```
processed = set()
if isinstance(statements, list):
    processed.update(statements)
else:
    processed.add(statements)
```